# Displaying array values in element grouped by key

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have the following data structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Golf
            [manufacturer] => 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Focus
            [manufacturer] => 2
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Jazz
            [manufacturer] => 
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Passat
            [manufacturer] => 1
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Toureg
            [manufacturer] => 1
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => Galaxy
            [manufacturer] => 2
        )
)
```

I want to display it like so:

```
<div class="container id1">
    ID: 1 - Golf
    ID: 4 - Passat
    ID: 5 - Toureg
</div>
<div class="container id2">
    ID: 2 - Focus
    ID: 6 - Galaxy
</div>
<div class="container">
    ID: 3 - Jazz
</div>
```

So my view code is going to output the above array that I tried to do like this:

```
foreach ($cars as $car){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    if ($car->manufacturer) {
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="container id'. $car->manufacturer .'">';
        echo $car->id . ' - ' . $car->title;
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="container">';
        echo $car->id . ' - ' . $car->title;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

But this outputs several empty `<div class="container"></div>` elements and only `<div class="container">ID: 1 - Golf</div>`, not like the desired output. How can I achieve the desired output with this array? Note, the Jazz does not have manufacturer set, so the `<div>` class should not have an idX set where X is the ID value of manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is sort the array based on the manufacturer which you can do using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), sorting entries with no manufacturer by the `id` value. Then you can loop over the cars, checking whether the manufacturer is the same as the previous car, and if so, outputting a new `<div>` element and closing the previous one (if required):

```
// sort based on manufacturer
usort($cars, function ($a, $b) { 
    if (!$a->manufacturer) {
        // if both null, sort by id
        if (!$b->manufacturer) return $a->id - $b->id;
        // otherwise sort null values last
        return 1;
    }
    if (!$b->manufacturer)
        // sort null values last
        return -1;
    return $a->manufacturer - $b->manufacturer;
});

$lastmfg = 0;
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    if (!$car->manufacturer || $car->manufacturer != $lastmfg) {
        if ($lastmfg !== 0) echo "</div>\n";
        echo '<div class="container'. ($car->manufacturer ?  ' id' . $car->manufacturer : '') .'">'. "\n";
    }
    echo 'ID: ' . $car->id . ' - ' . $car->title . "\n";
    $lastmfg = $car->manufacturer;
}
echo "</div>\n";
```

Output (for the expanded demo):

```
<div class="container id1">
ID: 1 - Golf
ID: 4 - Passat
ID: 5 - Toureg
</div>
<div class="container id2">
ID: 2 - Focus
ID: 6 - Galaxy
</div>
<div class="container id3">
ID: 9 - Phoenix
</div>
<div class="container">
ID: 3 - Jazz
</div>
<div class="container">
ID: 7 - Falcon
</div>
<div class="container">
ID: 8 - Commodore
</div>
<div class="container">
ID: 10 - Cressida
</div>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nVPGt)

Comment: That is _almost_ perfect. Two problems - one, the "no manufacturer assigned" cars are in one single `<div class="container">` instead of their own div, and two, I am not sure exactly what causes the re-ordering if manufacturer is not set. If I just print_r($cars) then the order is by ID 0>6, but putting this code in place, the "no manufacturer assigned" cars order appears sporadic - 9, 11, 8, 10, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7. Can those without a manufacturer be left in their default sort order?

Comment: @KalebThompson so if `manufacturer` is `null` you want them to sort by `id`?

Comment: @KalebThompson Is this what you want? https://3v4l.org/ZF27i If not, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Almost perfect; that's exactly what I was looking for, albeit each container without a manufacturer is now missing the closing </div>.

Comment: @KalebThompson sorry, forgot `null == 0`. Just needed to change the test to `!==` https://3v4l.org/nVPGt

Comment: Absolute perfection! Also, for introducing me to 3v4l.org - that is an awesome tool to have in the toolbox, so I'll be recommending you for a Knighthood!

Comment: Cool. I'll update the answer with that code. And yeah, 3v4l.org is great, so easy to quickly test code.

Comment: Answer accepted as it does the job perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @KalebThompson no worries - it was an interesting problem.